# eliminate indent from itemize starting from the second line

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I've seen many answers to the question of how not to indent the entries of a list with enumerate or itemize, but I couldn't find the answer to this other question: I want the first line to be as it is by default, but the rest of them aligned with the usual text. That is, if I use

```
[...] This is what I read in the New York Times: 
\begin{itemize}

\item Escalating his criticism of Hillary Clinton’s debate performances, 
Donald J. Trump came to a state battling a drug epidemic and suggested without 
any evidence on Saturday

\end{itemize}
```

I would get the second sentence "Donald J. Trump..." aligned at the same level of the item, but I want it to be aligned with the rest of the text which is outside the itemize environment.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short, compilable code you have tried so far ...

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tried anything, I don't know where to start...

Comment: You can improve your question by adding a minimal working example (MWE) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. See also question here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228

Comment: Are you happier now?

Comment: Are you happier now having written that? It's not about making us happy but about minimizing our effort to help you (and thus increasing your chances that actually someone spends the time). We should be able to copy and paste your code, and when compiling it we should be able to see your problem, and then we can start modifying the code. At the moment your code gives lots of errors (unrelated to your problem) because it doesn't start with `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you're after the `wide` option of `enumitem`. Here are two variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
 \usepackage{enumitem}

  \begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. %

[...] This is what I read in the New York Times:
\begin{itemize}[wide]

\item Escalating his criticism of Hillary Clinton’s debate performances,
Donald J. Trump came to a state battling a drug epidemic and suggested without
any evidence on Saturday

\end{itemize}
Unless your prefer this: %
\begin{itemize}[wide = 0pt]
\item Escalating his criticism of Hillary Clinton’s debate performances,
Donald J. Trump came to a state battling a drug epidemic and suggested without
any evidence on Saturday

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe your question has been answered here: [Left margin for 'custom' item of enumeration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160776/left-margin-for-custom-item-of-enumeration)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{(\alph*)}},leftmargin=0.5cm,align=left]
    \item Question
    \item[answer (a)] Answer
    \item Question
    \item[answer (b)] Answer
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, sorry, this doesn't work. This aligns the text in the second line at the same level at the enumeration symbol, not as the same level of the rest of the text in the document

Comment: but it changes the wanted margin, so you are expected to find the value to replace in the example.